# php Form with jquery validation issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

** Updated with additional code **

I am redesigning a site for someone and reusing some of the php code from the previous developer.  The form submits and does validation server-side on the process page.  This is obviously bad from a user experience perspective. I am trying to incorporate jquery validation.  I am more of a designer and have limited knowledge on php and moderate jquery.

Its a pretty straight forward form that has 2 submit options at the end.  1 button for paying with a check, 1 for paypal.

The code being used for these buttons is completely bypassing my jquery form validation.   If I put a simple submit button the jquery validation kicks.

This is the code for the 2 buttons being used.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').validate();
});     
</script>

<form id="lx" class="form-horizontal" action="reg_process.php" method="post" name="regform">



    <div class="row mbs">                
             <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname"><span class="font-standout">*</span> First Name: </label>
             <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="FirstName" class="form-control input-lg mrs mls" min="2" required  />
             </div>
        </div>



    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.regform.Submit.value = 'PayPal'; document.regform.submit()" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i><br/>
        Pay with Paypal Online
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.regform.submit()" class="btn btn-primary" >
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i><br/>
        Pay By Check
    </a>
```

The buttons are simply passing either paypal or null into the form submit process page and then redirecting after that.  Is there a way I can make this pass jquery validation and then submit with those values?

Comment: Post the rest of your code

Comment: Updated with more code

Comment: Don't remove the server side validation, just add validation to the client.

Comment: I can keep the server-side there.  But still need to know how to force jquery validation and still pass the 'Paypal' through if jquery validation passes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a rules object for the `FirstName` field and remove the attributes from the input element.

Also the following doesn't work:

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
document.regform.Submit.value = 'PayPal';
```

However if it did work there is a corner case, where the user clicks the `paypal` button but the form does not validate, the user then fixes the validation errors and submits the form with the `check` button. In this event the form will be submitted with `Submit=PayPal`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var form = $('#lx'), submit = $('input[name=Submit]', form);

  form.validate({
    rules: {
      FirstName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    }
  });

  // lets keep JavaScript out of the DOM
  $('#bypaypal, #bycheck').on('click', function(event) {
    var paymentType = event.target.id === 'bypaypal' ? 'PayPal' : '';
    submit.val(paymentType);
    form.submit();
  });

  // this is just for demo purposes, you don't need it 
  form.on('submit', function() {
    if (form.valid()) {
      alert('Form is valid: Submit="' + submit.val() + '"');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="lx" class="form-horizontal" action="reg_process.php" method="post" name="regform">

  <div class="row mbs">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname">
      <span class="font-standout">*</span> First Name:
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control input-lg mrs mls" />
      <input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="bypaypal" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>
    <br/>Pay with Paypal Online
  </a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="bycheck" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <br/>Pay By Check
  </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what's going on is the inline-javascript is hi-jacking the code and it never makes it to the jQuery validation. So remove it. Also, it's a good idea to add IDs to the `a` tag submit buttons to easily capture the click event. You also need to suppress the default action of an `a` tag, so use event.preventDefault (note that you must pass the event param into the `.click` function)

(1) Remove inline javascript.

(2) Assign IDs to your anchor tags.

(3) Then, use jQuery to test for click event.

[**working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/90dqa5pz/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<form id="lx" class="form-horizontal" action="reg_process.php" method="post" name="regform">
    <div class="row mbs">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname"><span class="font-standout">*</span> First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="FirstName" class="form-control input-lg mrs mls" min="2" required />
        </div>
    </div> 
    <a id="paypal_submit" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i><br/>
        Pay with Paypal Online
    </a>
    <a id="normal_submit" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i><br/>
        Pay By Check
    </a> 
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#paypal_submit, #normal_submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault; //stop a tag default action
    var submit_type = this.id.split('_')[0]; //paypal or normal
    var fn = $('#firstname').val();
    if (fn=='' || fn.length < 4){
        alert('Invalid first name');
        $('#firstname').css({'background':'yellow','border':'1px solid orange'}).focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        if (submit_type == 'paypal'){
            $('#lx').val('PayPal').submit();
        }else{
            $('#lx').submit();
        }
    }
});
```

---

If you have multiple fields to check, here is another jsFiddle Demo that shows how to handle that:

http://jsfiddle.net/tyvk15cg/

Comment: do you mean `$('#lx')` instead of `$('#ls')`?

Comment: No worries, it's just a slip of the index finger.

Comment: There is nothing about the jQuery Validate plugin in here.

Comment: Putting the `$('#lx').submit()` in both sides of the `if/else` doesn't make logical sense.  If it fires under both conditions, then it doesn't need to be in a conditional.

Comment: @Sparky You are right, but the value has to be set before hitting submit - that' s the point. It's inelegant code, but *some days you're the coder, and some days you're the beanie...*  This is not one of my better days... but hopefully I've given the OP some ideas, *further to the excellent suggestions of robbmj,* on how to resolve his question.

Comment: @Sparky Re jQuery plugin - for OP's requirements, it would be just as difficult -- if not more -- to implement the jQuery plugin than to implement a simple manual solution. I've used that plugin many times.

Comment: This solution also worked for me.    Thanks for your effort.. up voted.

Comment: Good enough if that's what the OP accepts.  However, I was merely pointing out that he asked about something more specific.